# Помогите разобраться с примером из книги: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

```
import re
phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'^\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d')
mo = phoneNumRegex.search("My number : 414-333-2745")
print('Найденный телефонный номер: ' + mo.group())
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Anki\import re.py", line 4, in 
>       print('Найденный телефонный номер: ' + mo.group()) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group

не работает,возвращает тип None(это я понял) ,но ведь в строке есть шаблон для регулярного выражения! зато чуть изменим строку на:

```
import re
phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'^\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d')
mo = phoneNumRegex.search("414-333-2745")
print('Найденный телефонный номер: ' + mo.group())
```

Вуаля:

> Найденный телефонный номер: 414-333-2745

Читал про кодировку в английской версии flow ,но не понял тот ли это случай.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Символ `^` означает, что строка обязана начинаться со следующего за ним символа (или типа). В вашем регулярном выражении строка обязана начинаться с любого целого числа `\d`, что и происходит во втором случае и поэтому работает как вы ожидаете. А в первом случае ваша строка начинается с буквы `М`, что не соответствует вашему регулярном выражению и поэтому возвращается None.

Уберёте галочку и все должно заработать как надо.

Answer (score 4):

Правильный ответ дал уже [Alexander Chernin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/235611/alexander-chernin). Я хочу только добавить, что результат метода `search()` *нужно всегда тестировать на значение `None`*, чтобы избежать вами приведенной ошибки:

```
import re
phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d')
mo = phoneNumRegex.search("My number : 414-333-2745")

if mo:
    print('Найденный телефонный номер: ' + mo.group()) 
else
    print('Телефонного номера нету.')                  # ошибки не будет
```

---

Примечание:

`if mo:`

сокращена форма команды

`if mo is not None:`

т.к. когда объект `mo` существует, он будет для команды `if` вычислен как `True`, пока `None` как `False`.

Comment: Я думаю выражение `\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d` можно заменить на `\d{3}-\d\{3}-\d{4}`

Comment: @OmertaOmerta, не стоит.